# Finding out what the NewSize is from code

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

Is it possible to display the java NewSize parameter the same way we can find the heap size?

I know the heap size can be found by using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Is there something similar for NewSize?

Comment: You can examine all the memory regions by looking at the MemoryManagerMXBean. The NewSIze is the sum of the eden and survivor regions.  Note: some systems might not have a new size.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Post this as an answer, it was pretty much what I needed!

Comment: I was hoping someone might flesh out the details. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want the `MemoryPoolMXBean` to get numerical values of the Eden Space and the Survivor Space:

```
for(java.lang.management.MemoryPoolMXBean memoryPoolMXBean :java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getMemoryPoolMXBeans())
{
    System.out.println("");
    try
    {
        System.out.println("PoolName\t" + memoryPoolMXBean.getName());
        System.out.println("Commited\t" + memoryPoolMXBean.getCollectionUsage().getCommitted());
        System.out.println("Init\t" + memoryPoolMXBean.getCollectionUsage().getInit());
        System.out.println("Max\t" + memoryPoolMXBean.getCollectionUsage().getMax());
        System.out.println("Used\t" + memoryPoolMXBean.getCollectionUsage().getUsed());
    }
    catch (NullPointerException npex)
    {
        npex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
PoolName    Code Cache
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.github.lyubent.example.App.main(App.java:40)

PoolName    Par Eden Space
Commited    0
Init    335544320
Max 335544320
Used    0

PoolName    Par Survivor Space
Commited    0
Init    41943040
Max 41943040
Used    0

PoolName    CMS Old Gen
Commited    0
Init    1728053248
Max 1728053248
Used    0

PoolName    CMS Perm Gen
Commited    0
Init    21757952
Max 85983232
Used    0
```